# why does a trigger cause all rows to be updated when it should only update one?

Tags: sqlite, triggers, sql-insert

The following trigger is intended only to cause the string value 'undefined' to be replaced by the DEFAULT value, but instead all inserted rows are affected:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (
 id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 mycolumn BOOLEAN DEFAULT '0');

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS onnull
AFTER INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.mycolumn = 'undefined'
BEGIN
    UPDATE mytable
      SET mycolumn = (SELECT dflt_value FROM pragma_table_info('mytable') WHERE name = 'mycolumn' ) ;
END;

INSERT INTO 'mytable' ('mycolumn') VALUES
      (true),
      (false),
      ('undefined');

select * from mytable;
```

The result of the `select` indicates that the "trigger" value was applied to all rows:

```
1|'0'
2|'0'
3|'0'
```

Is there a way to achieve the desired effect?

I am using `SQLite version 3.40.1 2022-12-28`.

Answer (score 0):

The update must be restricted to the row in question, e.g. by adding:

```
WHERE rowid=NEW.rowid
```